# deploying a java based web site

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, web

I have created an entire site which includes Jsp and html pages,servlets,java files,and i have used msaccess as the db.All thse have been created using eclipse.What is the best way to deploy this on the web?and how do i do it?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How have you deployed it so far, to do testing?

Comment: Apache Webserver + Tomcat. connect the two using ModJK

Comment: Oh yeah, and try to use something other than MS Access for the database if you plan on doing anything remotely serious with the web site.

Comment: I am planning to change the db to oracle. and what is modjk?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the WAR-format is designed for.

Look into how to package your stuff in a WAR form and use that.  Note that very few sites offer *both* Java and Access.  You may want to consider being database agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

do you already have a "java-capable" webserver running somewhere? Are you going to host it yourself or are you going to deploy it to some server hosted by some company?

As YK-47 already said tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/) in conjunction with apache webserver is a good choice. You might also want to have a look at jetty (http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)

As soon as you have the server running and accessible over the web you can deploy any java based web application there (i.e. a war-file).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I intend to host it myself.Iam still unclear on how i can make it available on both my network and the internet.kindly help

Comment: you can expose every internally (i.e. behind your router) running service to the outside (google for port forwarding). In case you have a dynamic ip you should consider using a dynamic dns provider to access your service from a non-changing URL. However be aware that opening ports to the outside world might be a security risk to your internal network. IMHO using some external hoster would be the better choice. What about trying one of the new and fancy cloudservices like (e.g. cloudbees, cloudfoundry, AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

A War file is definitely the easiest method.

If you turn your project into a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project it can automatically generate a [war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)  file for you, and even [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/appserver/goals.html) it to a webserver if you set it up to do so.

m2eclipse is the plugin you need to get for eclipse, you can then right click your project and go to Configure>Convert to Maven Project. Once this is done look in the Pom file it generates for you and select your output to war (I think by default it might be jar)

If you are new to Maven their website has a quick start guide which may be worth running through which will get you up to speed fast

[5 Minute Test](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

It is worth he effort to learn how to use Maven as in the long run will save you a lot of time... as you wont have to write build scripts

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Please could you provide a link which would explain me how to do it?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link which is a Maven 5 minute overview, and about the plugin you need